# Registered domain through Google apps

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I'm helping out a friend, he bought a domain through Google apps for a business email  e.g. mybusiness@mybusiness.com.  He now wants me to put a website for this domain e.g. www.mybusiness.com.

So he gave me login details for his Google apps account and after looking around i found login details for GoDaddy DNS control panel here.

http://oi57.tinypic.com/qoydfc.jpg

Now this only allows me to change DNS settings, where are the options, such as wordpress, mysql,cpanel etc?  These are the only login details he was given for Godaddy? I tried to login at Godaddy.com and these login details don't work, username doesn't exist.   When i visit e.g. www.mybusiness.com/cpanel i get a google error 404 page but he bought the domain?

Please tell me how this works. I simply want to put a website on the domain he bought with Google apps.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like your friend only bought the domain + google apps account. you didn't mention any hosting/server that he paid for. in this case, he needs to get web hosting wherever he likes, and just point the dns accordingly. your question is tagged with google-app-engine for some reason. So if you intend to use [google app engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/app-engine/) for web hosting, you need to create a project and [assign it the domain you purchased](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain).

Comment: this is more work than i wanted.  Do i need to download php & wordpress then?  Also if i use the domain for the website, will he still have the domain for the business email?

Comment: @DannyBrammel you need to get web hosting. if you choose a simple shared hosting they can install wordpress for you. and yes, you can use the domain for a website and for email at the same time